# Laravel throttle doesnt workin

Tags: php, json, laravel, back, throttling

On backend it works, but on frontend `x-ratelimit-remaining` header does not decrease. Maybe someone knows what is the reason. Thanks.

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\admin::class,
    ];
```

api.php

```
if (Request()->header('Authorization')) {
    Route::post('search', 'SearchController@search');//->middleware('throttle:30,1440', 'auth:api', 'admin');
} else {
    Route::post('search', 'SearchController@search');//->middleware('throttle:3,1440');
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your headers of `x-ratelimit-remaining`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a title more descriptive of the problem.